# Creating a Matrix in R from a dataset

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to convert data provided to us in a csv into a matrix. We have saved the data as an object (us_quarters) Its a simple dataset containing the name of a state, then the number of quarters produced at two separate mints for that state.

```
State    DenverMint PhillyMint

Delaware   401424    373400
one row for each state.
```

I am trying to create a side by side barplot of this data, and first need to convert the data into a matrix to work with it. The issue I seem to be struggling with is the fact that the state itself is a column so when I try to convert I end up with a jumbled mess of character values and integer values stored in massive lists.

```
x <- matrix(us_quarters,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(x) <- c("State", "DenverMint", "Phillymint")
x
```

produces this result

```
     State        DenverMint Phillymint
[1,] character,50 integer,50 integer,50
```

Everything I am trying to do requires the data to be formatted in this matrix in order to work with it properly and I am at a total loss as to how to proceed. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: `do.call(data.frame, x)` or even `data.frame(c(x))`

Comment: @Dave2e OP has a matrix of lists. Eg. `x<-t(as.matrix(as.list(iris)))` or simply `y<-t(as.list(iris))` OP wants to get the dataframe back

Comment: Once you have run the `do.call` you can then change the names with `names(y)<- colnames(x)`

Comment: There are possible ways to create a side by side barplot with data frame, without having to create a matrix. Could you show how the desired barplot looks like so that other users can show the ways to create it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use pivot_longer to group Denver and Philly mint?

```
df <- tribble(~state, ~den_mint, ~philly_mint, 
        'delaware', 401424,373400, 
        'newyork', 460858, 494023)

df %>% 
  mutate(state = as.factor(state)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("den_mint", "philly_mint"), names_to = "mint", values_to = "count") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mint, count)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~state) +
  coord_flip()
```